# How to protect SQL code in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, piracy-prevention

Is it possible to protect SQL 2008 stored procedure code from anyone`s eyes? Maybe some encryption, or assembling like dll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can save it ti the database in encrypted form, but if you do, make sure you have the original source code safely stored somewhere...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo 
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'foo' 
END
```

Unfortunately, there are at least two ways to defeat this mechanism. One is to run SQL Profiler while executing the stored procedure; this often can reveal the text of the procedure itself, depending on what the stored procedure does (e.g. if it has GO batches, dynamic SQL etc). If they miss the initial install, the user can delete the stored procedures or drop the database, start a Profiler trace, and ask you to re-create them (in which case they will capture the CREATE PROCEDURE statements). You can prevent Profiler from revealing the text to snoopers by embedding sp_password in the code, as a comment:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo 
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'foo' 
    -- comment: sp_password 
END
```

look at [MSDN Create Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259(SQL.80).aspx) documention

Comment: does this method have name? or maybe any Link?

Comment: +1 for the nice answer (although I personally see no need for the technique involved)

Comment: Unfortunately, it takes less than 5 mn on google to find a way to bypass the trivial encryption built in SQL server. If you really want to protect your code, you might want to look for a commercial solution